# Are some 3.5 and Pathfinder questions inherently too broad?

Tags: discussion, questions

The Dungeons and Dragons 3.X ecosystem is huge, with core books and splatbooks for essentially 3 different *almost compatible* systems.  We often have questions that ask for character or monster options from either D&D 3.5 or Pathfinder in very general terms.  The answer that spawned this question is [How does a PC make a permanent extradimensional space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47182/how-does-a-pc-make-a-permanent-extradimensional-space).

The problem I see is that you end up with not multiple sometimes overlapping list answers.  How do you decide which one is best without more detail?

<sub>We have 222 questions that are tagged both [dnd-3.5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) and [pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder), but many of these are comparing rules in the editions, or asking about how an effect might be handled.</sub>

Comment: Based on the answers it generated, that question isn't exceedingly broad.

Answer (score 17):

Well, some questions probably are. But that's like asking "are some questions about swords?" For the sheer number of questions these systems get, it's inevitably going to be true at some point.

I don't see any particular problem in practice with these tags. There's a lot of cases where the system overlap is sufficient that you actually can answer for both, or (particularly for non-strict RAW cases) something from one is easily compatible with the other.

The question you gave has list answers because there's more than one way to do the thing in question. There also isn't a good way to make the question specific enough to narrow it down to only one way of doing said thing, until the person asking question already knows how to do it (which would defeat the point of asking the question). Both answers are also pretty detailed already, I'm not sure how much more could be added without making them overly long.

I don't know, I'm just not seeing any problem in this case. It looks like things are working correctly.